# Converting PBF to GeoJSON using python3-gdal module

Tags: gdal, geojson, convert, python-3, pbf

How can I use the module python3-gdal to convert .pbf into .geojson using Python?

I've been exploring ogr in python3-gdal module but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I do a request, the response brings a pbf and I would like to do something like:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
import requests
response = requests.get(".../geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/17/129151/49004.pbf")
my_json = ogr.convert_this_to_pbf(response.content)
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`gdal.VectorTranslate`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#:%7E:text=VectorTranslate(destNameOrDestDS%2C%20srcDS%2C%20**kwargs)) function (basically the same as `ogr2ogr` commandline utility):

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

pbf = 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries@EPSG:900913@pbf/3/2/4.pbf'
ds = gdal.OpenEx(pbf, gdal.OF_VECTOR)  # note use of gdal.OpenEx, ogr is deprecated from gdal 2.0+
output = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries.geojson'
out_ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(output, ds)
```

[image]